# Не работает shortcode, который выводит список записей пользователя

Tags: wordpress

Не работает shortcode, который выводит список записей пользователя. Хотя через var_dump($query) выводятся все данные
functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('post_list', 'post_list_func');

function post_list_func( $atts) {

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'author' => get_current_user_id(),) 
    );

    while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция шорткода не должна ничего выводить на экран. Она должна вернуть строку.

```
add_shortcode('post_list', 'post_list_func');

function post_list_func( $atts) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'author' => get_current_user_id(),) 
    );

    $output = '';
    while ($query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: а что означает  ".= " ? первый раз такое вижу в присваивании

Comment: Обычный оператор php. Означает, что к строке $output надо присоединить то, что справа. То же самое, что `$output = $output . 'строка';`  http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php